# i want multiple dates in dropdown list in ejs filein which multiple dates are present

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
<% var date=new Date().getFullYear(); %>
         <select name="year">
         <%for(var i=date;i>1950;i--)
         {
         %>
         <option value='<%= i%>' /><%= i%> </option>
         <% }%>                 
        </select>
```

> Above code is giving me empty values in drop down list instead of dates. Please solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your code has a issue. You cannot use a function of date object while creating it. Update your code to below

```
<% var date=new Date();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
%>
<select name="year">
<%for(var i=year;i>1950;i--)
{
%>
    <option value='<%= i%>' /><%= i%> </option>
<% }%>                 
</select>
```

This will only print the year though not date. Hope this helps

Comment: sorry it was my mistake . My code is working correctly . By mistake i added '/' in option element..